# Creating jump anchors on Reddot

Tags: reddot

I'm trying to create a jump mark in a Reddot content component. So if I had a link like

```
<A href="#Q1">Question 1</A>
```

then if I were to next re-load the Standard View (either by closing and re-opening the form, or going into Source View, then Standard View), it appends a URL in front of the href, such that it looks like

```
<A href="<CMS generated URL here>#Q1">Question 1</A>
```

If this was done via Standard View and then saved and closed without re-loading Standard View via the methods mentioned above, then it works fine, but if some time in the future we need to make changes to it, then we'll have to re-do all the links since re-loading Standard View makes the CMS append the URL in front of the jump links again. The CMS generated URL is different from the page we are trying to access, so it creates problems of being sent to an error page.

I've tried referencing the link to return to the page, then appending the jump at the back of it, but that doesn't seem to work as when the page is published, the jump at the back disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, Reddot doesn't seem to like it if you enclose those sort of jump anchors in an ordered/unordered list. If I don't use lists, the CMS generated URL is not appended by switching views.

If anyone can offer an explanation to this behaviour, that'd be most appreciated.